# culture fallback

Tags: c#, .net, globalization, cultureinfo

I assume the following code is Correct,

CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.GetCulture("en-US");
Assert.IsTrue(culture.GetConsoleFallbackUICulture().Name == "en");

but it is not, culture.GetConsoleFallbackUICulture().Name is still "en-US", I want to know what is the API to get the fallback culture.

Thanks
Jeff

Comment: I assume the following code is .Net? Please tag properly.

Answer (score 3):

This is correct, en-US does not need to fallback, that's why it returns en-US.

Only cultures in this list are affected: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getconsolefallbackuiculture.aspx

EDIT: if you want to do what's in your comment, use the [CultureInfo.Parent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.parent.aspx) property.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to mimic the .net culture fallback behavior, I want to get cutlure "en-US"'s parent cutlure, I assume it is "en", and "en" 's parent is Cutlure.InvariantCulture, How do I achieve this?

Comment: Please edit your original question... I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.GetCulture("en-US");
Assert.IsFalse(culture.IsNeutralCulture); // en-US is NOT Neutral
Assert.IsTrue(culture.Parent.Name == "en"); // Our parent's culture is the neutral english culture
Assert.IsTrue(culture.Parent.IsNeutralCulture); // en is Neutral
Assert.IsTrue(culture.Parent.Parent.Name == ""); // Our grandparent's culture is the invariant culture
```